# Where is the error in my function for derivative of polynomial using Horner's method?

Tags: c, numerical-methods, dev-c++

I was using horners method to create code that could calculate a polynomial, and its derivative for any set of coefficients that im given. Horner's method was working perfectly when i had values hardcoded, but when i changed my code to take any input from the command line prompt, horner's derivative started printing out crazy numbers with dozens of zeros. but horner's method for the polynomial is being calculated properly still. I don't exactly know where the error is in this code.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

  double horner(double *coeffs, int s, double x)
{
  int i;
  double res = 0.0;

  for(i=s-1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    res = res * x + coeffs[i];
  }
  return res;
}

double hornerDerivative(double *coeffs, int s_1, double x_1)
{
  int i_1;
  double res_1 = 0.0;

  for(i_1 = s_1; i_1 >= 1; i_1--)
  {
    res_1 = res_1 * x_1 + i_1*coeffs[i_1];
  }
  return res_1;
}

double newton(double *coeffs, double a, double b, double eps)
{
       int N = 0;
       double c = ((a+b)/2);

       while(N < 10)
       {
               double y = horner(coeffs, sizeof(coeffs), c);
               double y_derivative = hornerDerivative(coeffs, sizeof(coeffs), c);
               double c_1 = c - (y/y_derivative);
               printf("c: %f\t",c);
               printf("y: %f\t",y);
               printf("y_der: %f\t",y_derivative);
               printf("c_1: %f\n",c_1);
               if(fabs(c_1-c)<eps)
               {
                    return c_1;                   
               }
               c = c_1;
               N = N + 1;
       }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("# of arguments%d\n\n\n\n", argc);
  double coeffs[argc-3];

  double a = atof(argv[argc-2]);
  double b = atof(argv[argc-1]);
  double eps = .001;

  int i;
  for(i=1; i < argc-2; i++)
  {
           coeffs[i-1] = atof(argv[argc-2-i]);
  }

  printf("The root of the equation is: %f\n", newton(coeffs, a, b, eps));
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I am getting.

```
C:\Dev-Cpp>ProgrammingAssignment1.exe 1 -6 4 12 1 4
# of arguments7



c: 2.500000     y: 0.125000     y_der: 61390858609268995000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000     c_1: 2.500000
The root of the equation is: 2.500000
```

As you can see, horner's method is calculating the polynomial just fine, but it isn't calculating the derivative properly. This is consistently the same error no matter what examples I use for the coefficients from the list my professor gave me.

Comment: you should not use an image as a code. use text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code in the question directly — do not use images of your code because it is unreadable and uncopyable and untestable and therefore undebuggable.

Comment: like @roottraveller has suggested, you should never post images of code. Apart from that, don't just copy paste the entire code you are trying to run. Create a [MCVE] that appropriately demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You should try printing the `coeff`s after you read them to determine where the exact problem is.

Comment: `horner(coeffs, sizeof(coeffs), c);` doesn't do what you think it does. `coeffs` is a pointer, so `sizeof(coeffs)` is the size of a pointer. It is not the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Don't add more pictures!  Show the text of the output in the question!  In the C tag, pictures are bad unless you're actually doing graphics, which you are manifestly not doing.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed, you have some problems in your code:

- Usage of `sizeof`.

  - `sizeof <array>` will return the size of  **in bytes**.
  - `sizeof <pointer>` will return the size of a pointer on your system typically 4 (32 bits arch) or 8 (64 bits arch).

  Look at this code:

  ```
  void foo(int * p)
  {
      printf("sizeof pointer is %z\n", sizeof p);
  }   
  void bar()
  {
      int a[256];
      printf("sizeof array is %z\n", sizeof a);
      foo(a);
  }
  ```

  It will print:

  ```
  sizeof array is 1024
  sizeof pointer is 8
  ```

  So you can't use `sizeof(coeffs)`
- How do you handle when Newton's method make more than 10 step to converge? You should return some value if condition `fabs(c_1-c)<eps` is never met (why not with some warning?)

---

One solution could be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

double horner(double *coeffs, int s, double x)
{
    int i;
    double res = 0.0;

    for(i=s-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        res = res * x + coeffs[i];
    }
    return res;
}

double hornerDerivative(double *coeffs, int s_1, double x_1)
{
    int i_1;
    double res_1 = 0.0;

    for(i_1 = s_1; i_1 >= 1; i_1--)
    {
        res_1 = res_1 * x_1 + i_1*coeffs[i_1];
    }
    return res_1;
}

/* New parameter here: cnt the number of elements in coeffs */
double newton(double *coeffs, size_t cnt, double a, double b, double eps)
{
   int N = 0;
   double c = ((a+b)/2);

   while(N < 10)
   {
        /* replacing sizeof... by cnt */
        double y = horner(coeffs, cnt, c);
        /* replacing sizeof... by cnt */
        double y_derivative = hornerDerivative(coeffs, cnt, c);
        double c_1 = c - (y/y_derivative);
        printf("c: %f\t",c);
        printf("y: %f\t",y);
        printf("y_der: %f\t",y_derivative);
        printf("c_1: %f\n",c_1);
        if(fabs(c_1-c)<eps)
        {
            return c_1;                   
        }
        c = c_1;
        N = N + 1;
   }

   /* always return some value */
   fprintf(stderr, "Warning newton do not converge in 10 steps...\n")
   return c;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("# of arguments%d\n\n\n\n", argc);
    double coeffs[argc-3];

    double a = atof(argv[argc-2]);
    double b = atof(argv[argc-1]);
    double eps = .001;

    int i;
    for(i=1; i < argc-2; i++)
    {
        coeffs[i-1] = atof(argv[argc-2-i]);
    }

    /* pass the number of elements in coeffs array */
    printf("The root of the equation is: %f\n", newton(coeffs, argc-3, a, b, eps));    
    return 0;
}
```